# emulator: ERROR: can't find the emulator executable

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, opensuse

Event log
[image]

This is what I get when I try to run my Nexus 6P AVD. I'm using OpenSUSE.

When I try using the command line emulator, it says the same thing. I tried starting an AVD which didn't exit (i.e. tried running the AVD "test" even though it wasn't there), and it said something about "test" not being there. This shows that emulator is indeed installed. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you figure out what was happening?

Comment: @zach I decided to use Arch, and installed Java and Android Studio in my new Arch system, and it just worked